# JS library with map and timeline integration

Tags: javascript, maps

Looking for a js library that offer great interaction with maps.

I am building a Angular application that should have a timeline with certain dates, selecting a date should highlight points of interest on a map. Clicking on one of those points, should display a popup with media content (images / videos).

I have been looking into libraries such as D3.js and leaflet.js. Both might be viable options, but I have no experience in either and I find it hard to choose. Maybe there are other libraries that does the job even better?